# Changing segment content onPress

Tags: react-native, native-base, segment

I have segments and I want them to act as tabs. I tried using `react-navigation` `onPress` of each segment but it doesn't look nice.

I want the segments to stay **fixed** at the top and on clicking each one  the *content should change* **or** *call a specific component* without reloading or noticing that the screen has changed.

```
<Segment>
  <Button first>
    <Text>Puppies</Text>
   </Button>
   <Button>
    <Text>Kittens</Text>
    </Button>
    <Button last active>
      <Text>Cubs</Text>
    </Button>
</Segment>
<Content>
  <Text>Awesome segment</Text>
</Content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segments can be customized as a `react-navigation` single screen separated into multiple components which can be rendered on demand.

### Example

(Using native-base components)

```
state = {
    activePage:1,
}

selectComponent = (activePage) => () => this.setState({activePage})

_renderComponent = () => {
  if(this.state.activePage === 1)
    return <Component1/> //... Your Component 1 to display
  else 
    return <Component2/> //... Your Component 2 to display
}

render() {
  return ( 
    <Container>
      <Header>
       <Left />
       <Body>
         <Segment>
           <Button active={this.state.activePage === 1}
              onPress={this.selectComponent(1)}><Text>Component 1</Text></Button>
           <Button  active={this.state.activePage === 2}
              onPress= {this.selectComponent(2)}><Text>Component 2</Text></Button>
         </Segment>
        </Body>
        <Right/>
       </Header>
       <Content padder>
        {this._renderComponent()}
       </Content>
      </Container>
  )
}
```

You can customize it to add more components based on the conditions set above

### Edit

Supposing you navigate to a particular screen that also contains `Segment`, the on some item button click you can do

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('OtherSegmentScreen', {activePage: this.state.activePage})
```

And on that page receive the `props` as

```
const {navigate} = this.props.navigation
const previousActiveSegment = navigate.getParams('activePage', '1') //... 1 is default value that you can set
```

Comment: how can i change the style for the active state?

Comment: The `active` tag would take care of it as mentioned, but if you need to change the styles you can always do `<Button style={[... other styles, this.state.activePage === 1 : {... activeStyles}]}` per button as mentioned.

Comment: is it possible to disable other segments when one of them is active?

Comment: That can be disabled , if you pass the state of current segment as props to another component and check it based on the usage

Comment: Pritish Vaidya can you update it in the example please?